# SQL query isn't working when embedded in java

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, database-connection, nsurlconnection, sqlresultsetmapping

I'm trying to connect the SQL plus database with java but it's not working , I'm using netbeabs ide 8.0.2 
Here i have pasted following cod

e in my submit button but when I  execute it then it goes for the JOptionPane which is in else part whereas it should go for the if part. I'm working on it but I've got no solution can u help please

```
String sql ="select * from ADMINTABLE where APOST = ? and USERNAME = ? and PASSWORD = ?";
try {
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sql)
          pst.setString(1, jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
    pst.setString(2,jTextField1.getText());
    pst.setString(3, Arrays.toString(jPasswordField1.getPassword()));
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
        con.close();
        setVisible(false);
        Admin ob = new Admin();
        ob.setVisible(true);
    } else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"username and password not matched Please Enter Again !!!");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
```

Comment: Please fix formatting.

Comment: done ! please have a look on the code hope u can solve my problem

Comment: It seems you are storing the password in plain text. Since this is highly insecure, I would suggest to hash the password instead.